# Where do I store custom functions that call custom page template files?

Tags: functions, customization

I've created a Wordpress Page template called head.php

I then went into /wp-includes/general-template.php and by replicating the default get_header() function that is already there I added this new custom function underneath :

```
function get_head( $name = null ) 
{

    do_action( 'get_head', $name );

    $templates = array();

    $name = (string) $name;

    if ( '' !== $name )
    {
        $templates[] = "head-{$name}.php";
    }

    $templates[] = 'head.php';

    if ('' == locate_template($templates, true))
    {
        load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme-compat/head.php');
    }
}
```

I then called the above function in one of my Custom Page Template files and it worked fine.

Then Wordpress updated the /wp-includes/general-template.php file and my custom function got overwritten.

So my question is, where should I place the above function so that it never gets overwritten either by Wordpress updates or theme-specific updates?

And do I place the above function as is (in the new file you will suggest) without including anything more ? (or does the /wp-includes/general-template.php file include other stuff as well and that's why my function works form within that file and it will not work in some other file?)

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not create a `header-custom.php` with your custom template code and then call `get_header( 'custom' )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place this function into your theme's `functions.php`.

Never mess with the core WordPress files (anything in the wp-includes, wp-admin directory). An error can lead to a non functioning site, and the files get updated.

WordPress never updates your custom themes, so this is the way to go.

Of course, if you have a lot of functions, you can create a `library` directory in your theme and include all the files containing the functions.

You can also create a Plugin for your custom functions - but in your case, as your theme relies on the function, it should be included in the theme.

Comment: Thank you for your reply fischi. And like I said in my OP, do I simply paste in the above function into my functions.php in my custom theme ? Don't I need to include anything like `@subpackage template` etc ?

Comment: No, you just copy and paste it in your `functions.php`, and you are good to go. Maybe you will have to adjust the paths.

Comment: OK thanks a lot fischi that actually worked! What I did is I duplicated the default `twentyfifteen` theme folder, renamed the new folder, changed all the appropriate `@......` in all of its files and the went into its `functions.php` file and pasted my function. So this `functions.php` file will never get updated/overwiteen because it resides in a custom theme folder whereas if I were using the `functions.php` file found in the `twentyfifteen` theme folder this could get updated/overwritten in the future by some twentyfifteen update correct? Just clarifying things in my head as I'm new to WP..

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You should read into Child Themes and Plugin Development here - this would be a good starting point to show you the direction how you can alter WordPress.